# The new <dialog> tag is not found in android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-ktx

I saw that dialog fragments are now supported in the Android Jetpack Navigation component. When i use the dependency androidx.navigation:navigation-ui with its latest version, it works perfectly. However, when i use the dependency android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx with its latest version (1.0.0), the dialog tag is not found and it seems to be outdated compared to the other dependancy. Can someone explain why and also explain which dependency is better to us ?

According to google, if you're using Kotlin, it's better to use the -ktx one but i find that it's missing lots of features compared to the other.

Comment: `android.arch.navigation` is the older Support Library/Architecture Components edition. Always prefer `androidx` artifacts where possible.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Navigation release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.0.0-rc02):

> Navigation 1.0 stable will be the last release using the Support Library dependencies; all future development beyond 1.0 will be based on AndroidX and build upon the 2.0 stable release.

Support for `<dialog>` destinations was added in [Navigation 2.1.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha03), which would mean that it is only supported by the `androidx.navigation` packaging used by Navigation 2.X versions.